# How to make a correct login function with GTK?

Tags: c, gtk

I am using GTK and the C language to create a GUI to a function that connect and create an account for a user . I try to retrieve the string that a user write in a gtk_entry then compare it with the acc.txt file (who contain successively an account name , then a password etc...My code look like that :

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <gmodule.h>

void Login(GtkWidget *pLogBtn, GSList *lLogMdp)
{
GtkWidget *pEntryID;
GtkWidget *pEntryMDP;
GtkWidget *pLabInfo;
const gchar *sIDEntry;
const gchar *sMDPEntry;
FILE* acc = NULL;
char accAct[50] = "";
int CheckAccEgal = 2;
int CheckMdpEgal = 2;

pEntryID = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lLogMdp, 0);
pEntryMDP = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lLogMdp, 1);
pLabInfo = (GtkWidget*) g_slist_nth_data(lLogMdp, 2);

sIDEntry = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(pEntryID));
sMDPEntry = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(pEntryMDP));

acc = fopen("data/acc.txt", "r");

if (acc != NULL)
{
    while (fgets(accAct, 50, acc) != NULL) 
    {
        CheckAccEgal = strcmp(sIDEntry, accAct);
        if (CheckAccEgal == 0)
        {
            fgets(accAct, 50, acc);
            CheckMdpEgal = strcmp(sMDPEntry, accAct);
            if (CheckMdpEgal == 0)
            {
                gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(pLabInfo), "Connexion accepter");
            }
            else
            {
                gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(pLabInfo), "Nom d'utilisateur et mot de passe non correspondant");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(pLabInfo), sIDEntry);
        }
    }
    fclose(acc);
}

gtk_widget_show_all(pLabInfo);
}
```

I dont know why but it's always the last choice who is chosen , even when i write exactly an account and the pass who correspond in my two gtk_entry. It's a callback function , here's the main function who correspond :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include "RandFuncGTK.h"
#include <gmodule.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
GtkWidget *pWindow;
GtkWidget *pBoiteTotal;
GtkWidget *pLabID;
GtkWidget *pLabMDP;
GtkWidget *pEntryID;
GtkWidget *pEntryMDP;
GtkWidget *pBoiteBtn;
GtkWidget *pLogBtn;
GtkWidget *pCreateAccBtn;
GtkWidget *pLabInfo;
GSList *lLogMdp = NULL;

gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

pWindow = CreateWindow(pWindow, "GtkTest1", 200, 320);

pBoiteTotal = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_VERTICAL, 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pWindow), pBoiteTotal);

pLabID = gtk_label_new("<span weight=\"bold\">Identifiant :</span>");
gtk_label_set_use_markup(GTK_LABEL(pLabID), TRUE);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pBoiteTotal), pLabID);

pEntryID = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pBoiteTotal), pEntryID);
lLogMdp = g_slist_append(lLogMdp,(GtkWidget*) pEntryID);

pLabMDP = gtk_label_new("<span weight=\"bold\">Mot de passe :</span>");
gtk_label_set_use_markup(GTK_LABEL(pLabMDP), TRUE);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pBoiteTotal), pLabMDP);

pEntryMDP = gtk_entry_new();
gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(pEntryMDP), FALSE);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pBoiteTotal), pEntryMDP);
lLogMdp = g_slist_append(lLogMdp,(GtkWidget*) pEntryMDP);

pBoiteBtn = gtk_box_new(GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL, 0);
gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(pBoiteTotal), pBoiteBtn);

pLogBtn = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Login");
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pBoiteBtn), pLogBtn, TRUE, FALSE, 5);

pCreateAccBtn = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Creation de compte");
gtk_box_pack_end(GTK_BOX(pBoiteBtn), pCreateAccBtn, TRUE, FALSE, 5);

pLabInfo = gtk_label_new("");
gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(pBoiteBtn), pLabInfo, TRUE, FALSE, 5);
lLogMdp = g_slist_append(lLogMdp,(GtkWidget*) pLabInfo);

gtk_widget_show_all(pWindow);

g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pWindow), "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(pLogBtn), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(Login), lLogMdp);

gtk_main();

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I test and the two `gtk_entry` are successfully written in the string and the function read correctly the acc.txt , i think that the problem come from the `strcmp()` what did i do wrong ?

Here's the acc.txt

[image: acc.txt]

Thanks for help

Comment: You need to read the user-name and password pair from the file *as a pair*. If `strcmp(sIDEntry, accAct);` fails you go out of sync with your reading (the next time you read from the "user-name" from the file, it will be the password of the previous user).

Comment: Your solution user3121023 don't work , and can you explain a bit in deep please Some programmer dude ? I'm new in programming and i didn't understand

Comment: In the `Login` function you have a loop, `while (fgets(accAct, 50, acc) != NULL)`, which read the user-name. Then you do `CheckAccEgal = strcmp(sIDEntry, accAct);`. If `CheckAccEgal` is non-zero (i.e. the strings are not equal, see the comment by @user3121023 for one reason) your loop continues and again read a user-name. The problem is that the next line in the file isn't a user-name, it's a *password*. The reading isn't synchronized. You must read *both* the user-name *and* the password.

Comment: The problem with reading the password as a user-name would be *very* obvious if you learned how to debug your program. For example, using a debugger you can step through your code, statement by statement, while monitoring variables and their values and see how they change. Knowing how to debug your own programs, and knowing how to use a debugger is required for any programmer, even hobbyist programmers.

Comment: Thanks for the help , i think i understand

Comment: I fix the problem but the programs still don't work . Now the username and password are in the same string compare to a string in acc.txt and i changed the disposition in acc.txt . Any advice @Someprogrammerdude ? 
Here's the new loop where accAll contain the string with  username and password :

`while (fgets(accAct, 50, acc) != NULL) 
{   
CheckAccEgal = strcmp(accAll, accAct);
 if (CheckAccEgal == 0)
 {
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(pLabInfo), "Connexion accepter");
} 
}`

Comment: Use different strings for the user-name and the password?

Comment: Yes , thanks a lot for the help but it was just a problem of cursor , i had some fseek and i resolve the problem , thanks a lot !